# How to return unique message each time for a particular team

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aceb85/2) which contains team id and message id. Each time when I run a query I have to get a **unique** msg_id for each team.

Example:

```
ID  TEAM_ID  MSG_ID
1    1        10
2    1        11
3    2        12
4    2        13
5    2        14
```

Valid outputs:

1.

```
TEAM_ID        MSG_ID
   1             11
   2             13
```

2.

```
TEAM_ID        MSG_ID
   1             10
   2             12
```

Comment: Are you just wanting to return one random MSG_ID for each TEAM_ID or is there a criteria for returning specific MSG_IDs each time you run the query?

Comment: I want a random msg_id for each team_id

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return one random related MSG_ID for each TEAM_ID:

```
SELECT t.TEAM_ID,
    (SELECT MSG_ID
     FROM team_message
     WHERE TEAM_ID = t.TEAM_ID
     ORDER BY RAND()
     LIMIT 1) MSG_ID
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TEAM_ID
      FROM team_message) t;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aceb85/6)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM team_message ORDER BY rand()) as t GROUP BY TEAM_ID;
```